# Hide week days in full calendar dynamically?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to hide week days dynamically in full calendar. I have check boxes for week days in agenda week, if I am un check any week day like monday that week day hide in agenda week and if I check again that day show again.

I know hidden days is the option but not able to handle dynamically.

```
hiddenDays: [ 2, 4 ],
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Define what `dynamically` means

Comment: @charlietfl dynamically means when my calendar is fully rendered and I am in week agenda and I want to hide any week day on check box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either reload the page (and store your options in cookies, what i do)
or you can try to call .fullCalendar( 'render' ) after you make the change to the options.